# Excute the action occur by back button through an html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The point is that I have a form that is created through AJAX and then the user enter data then submit the form, then server forward him to another page, the user can return back to the previous page through the back button.

I want to create a button that executes the same action that the back button executes. What is the code that I can put it here ...

```
$("input[name='back']").click(function(){
  // what should I write here?

});
```

Comment: It works, can you put it in an answers section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `window.history.back();`.  Here's some additional info on the topic:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$("input[name='back']").click(function(){
  window.history.back();
});
```